# read sniffing data over tcp

Tags: c#, tcp, network-programming

i'm developing application that is listening to the data coming to the pc and store it in a db
when i'm trying to use any sniffing software  it decode the data and i can read it...
but in my code  ....i cant read it at all
it come in a format  like that

```
1822262151622341817118815518211616121520941131921572041519912321413018224510453482062312258624219217426213385792952422362282081777270129716688629114817282188771708157542505055171418651781981425595109572128317191993018793431541418175198551682143218916536118562071014546919618158204181231187237183188160147127165111798312311810419822146114761993113815821216617541542372062129733198212250147199288115346102031191275215728146245198190171121209115149107193226253199151253205183146112072202559697791491441131572351381412278441552554817712614110121823714822712523618924690185291182071331471286244143181469018522814822821118012620321315924832238219115405615512392145202385512115735771691111055935782371281492476567165158924021493139815144225143762294713291762001113814720516216041120169912317914878167571392103510118386589521910621319622274158971538465206168139190127867123282255271781242497522124211517622131122113236255230254211206911242051832545515823012124925217318223920523316923122925514321122343602492471242........
```

can any one tell me what kind of data  is that  and any code to solve it out??

Comment: i tried this one
System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(tcpHeader.Data)
and I'm able to get the data...but when i run it and wait for the data(it's in XML format)
i got it in many packets the it's hard to reread it again...
what should i do?
do i have to collect the data from every packets then add it all to get the whole message?
or is there is a library to do that in the .net

Comment: Could you be a bit more specific on what kind of tool/library/etc. you use to sniff this data ? And how are you printing/converting this data you get hold of ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To see what a real packet sniffer looks like, check out [WireShark](http://www.wireshark.org).  There are many different protocols over TCP, and many of them are binary.  Those that aren't may be using unicode characters, which are two-byte characters so an ascii display of them would be meaningless.

Anyway, the data you're displaying is pretty meaningless.  It looks like decimal data, are you concatenating a bunch of decimal representations of the binary stream interpreted as byte or integer values?  That would explain it.  You should start by running the stream through `System.TextEncoding.ASCII.Decode`  You'll probably see some recognizable strings.  Then try `System.TextEncoding.Unicode.Decode`, etc.

Answer (score 2):

No, we cannot. And the reason is simple, we don't know what application you are sniffing.

That stream of data could mean anything.

But, I suggest you print the data in hexadecimal. Maybe the data would make more sense.